# Dynamic Grid Build based on MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this bit of code that extracts the table headers and then the column data as I don't know what the headers are. Its working perfectly but I cant get the table layout to stop breaking Currently all my data is in the first column instead of under the correct header. Any ideas why ?

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <?php       
                            $colnames = json_decode($colnames); 
                            foreach($colnames as $header) {                                                         
                            ?>
                                <th><?php echo $header->Field ?></th>
                            <?php
                            }                       
                    ?>
                    <th>
                        Options
                    </th>
                </tr>

                <?php       

                        $none = true;                       

                        foreach($colnames as $header) {   

                            echo "<tr>";

                            $field = $header->Field;
                            foreach($colojects as $object) {

                                    $none = false;                          
                                    echo "<td>".$object->$field."</td>";

                            }

                            echo "<td> [ Edit ] [ Delete ]</td>";

                            echo "<tr>";
                        }   


                ?>              

                <?php
                    if ($none){
                        echo "<tr><td>You currently have no data for this databin ".$_GET['DatabinName']."</td></tr>";  
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I only had to swap around the search foreach. Solution below

```
<?php       

                        $none = true;   

                        foreach($colojects as $object) {

                            $none = false;  

                            echo "<tr>";

                                foreach($colnames as $header) { 

                                    $field = $header->Field;


                                    echo "<td>".$object->$field."</td>";

                                }

                            echo "<td> [ Edit ] [ Delete ]</td>";

                            echo "</tr>";
                        }   


                ?>
```

Comment: It seems that there is also a typo, in the end of `foreach($colojects as $object) {` loop, you have to have echo "</tr>"; instead of echo "<tr>";

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for spotting that. Appreciated!